# How to add colour to grout for wall tiles

Tags: bathroom, grout, tiling

I'm preparing to tile a bathroom wall with white 100x200mm tiles. For aesthetic reasons, I'd like to use contrasting grout in a bright vivid colour. All the pre-coloured grouts I can find for sale are shades of grey and beige. What would be the best way to add colour to white tile grout?

I'm leaning towards stirring paint into pre-mixed grout, or else mixing my own grout replacing some of the water with paint. But I'm not sure what type of paint to use, how intense a colour I could reasonably expect, and whether doing this might affect the grout's ability to do its job.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, i would look into dyes or [pigments](https://www.directcolors.com/product/concrete-pigment/) for concrete .

Mix it into a white grout. experiment with colors and ratios, take notes so you can scale up when you find the combo you like.

A quick web search found [this web site](https://www.concretenetwork.com/concrete/concrete_dyes/) as just an example.

I Also found [this tutorial](https://www.hometalk.com/11594295/how-to-grout-in-bright-colors?expand_all_questions=1),

But wait, *there is more*. If you act now i will include a link to a handy search engine where **You also can** [use the internet to find out things](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffcm).